# Is it possible to use Angular form validation with ngx-datatable?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm presenting data using ngx-datatable so that the user can dynamically add or remove rows and save those changes.  But I would like to be able to use Angular's built-in form validation for any newly added rows.  Is doing this even possible?